# why formatted data in datagridview cell sent to textbox removes formatting?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox

I have `datagridview` control with a column formatted to have **currency values**. The data was **NOT** bound to the `datagridview` using **data binding**, it was simply assigned to each column. i have added a `cellDoubleClick` event to send value in cells to textboxes. But when currency values were sent to textboxes they removed formatting and it happened automatically ie. the $ sign and grouping of digits gets removed. Why this happens? and how do i make it not do it?

Here is some screen shots

all loaded data with formatting to the datagridview control
[image]

double click on a cell send data to textboxes
[image]

Here is the code that sends data to textboxes

```
private void dgvRooms_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cmbBlockCode.Text = dgvRooms[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().Trim();
        cmbLevels.Text = dgvRooms[2, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().Trim();
        tbxRoomNo.Text = dgvRooms[0, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().Trim();
        tbxAval.Text = dgvRooms[3, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().Trim();
        tbxRentWeek.Text = dgvRooms[4, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().Trim(); //String.Format("{0:C2}", );
        tbxBondAmount.Text = dgvRooms[5, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().Trim();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {                
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code here to understand what may be the cause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*..the $ sign and grouping of digits get removed. Why does this happen? And how do I make it not do it?*

The `Value` is the value and you should be glad for this : With all the formatting in it, how could you still use it in a calculation.. etc?

To get it **with** the formatting you can copy its `FormattedValue` like this:.

```
tbxRentWeek.Text = dgvRooms[4, e.RowIndex].FormattedValue.ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: Therefore the value property contains the raw value : ), TY